# PHP Crack: Opening Dictionary

Tags: php

I am using PHP on Windows and I am trying to use:

`crack_opendict('./words');`

However, I get an error :

`Warning: crack_opendict(): Could not open crack dictionary: ./words`

I have been reading instructions and they mention that there should be three files, but they are being created in Linux and I haven't found a workaround for Windows.

Comment: So what are you pointing to?  There should be three files in that directory... words.pwd, words.hwm, and words.pwi.  Are you just pointing to wrong place / pwd?  Use full path perhaps.

Comment: I just have a words file. 

Yes, I know it should have those three files but the only way I have found to generate them is using Linux.

Comment: Correct.  As docs state, you need the binaries that CrackLib generates, not a text file of your dict.  And yes, easier to compile on a linux OS as with most source code.  Could try this; https://github.com/mausch/cracklib-win32

Comment: Thanks, I found the instructions vague, but I noticed that the project already came with a .pwd and .pwi files, so I didn't need to create my own for now.